# Convert youtube starts playing time to second - Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

What the best way to convert the following starts playing time (1h20m25s) to second using javascript.

**MODIFIED!**

```js
var hms = '1h20m00s',
  H = hms.split('h')[0],
  M = hms.substring(
    hms.lastIndexOf("h") + 1,
    hms.lastIndexOf("m")
  ),
  S = hms.substring(
    hms.lastIndexOf("m") + 1,
    hms.lastIndexOf("s")
  );

var spt = parseInt(H) * 60 * 60 + parseInt(M) * 60 + parseInt(S);
console.log(spt);
```

Comment: Is it always in that exact format?

Comment: hms, ms or or only s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a clear question, hope this will help you :

```js
// Assuming time is always in 99h99m99s format
var time = "1h20m25s";
// Extract hours
var h = parseInt(time.split("h")[0]);
var theRest = time.split("h")[1];
// Extract minutes
var m = parseInt(theRest.split("m")[0]);
// Extract seconds
var s = parseInt(theRest.split("m")[1]);
// Converting to seconds
var result = h*3600 + m*60 + s
document.write(time + ' in seconds : ' + result)
```

Comment: Thank you, what is the best way? this or the one I just added in my question above.

Comment: your code seems to be more clear and easy to understand :)